# transform array in following way using underscore

Tags: underscore.js

I have a json array object . I want to group by data based on column "Store.Zone.Name" , sorting order by "Store.Zone.SortingOrder" and perform aggregation on matrix columns such as count of "Name". Below are JSON array

Objects

Array[100]

0: Object 
1: Object 
2: Object 
3: Object

0: Object 
Name: "3/16 Dup lead"
Store: {Zone:{Name:"North",Description:"The North zone of JVM Store",SortingOrder:0}}

1: Object

Name: "3/16 AdB lead"
Store: {Zone:{Name:"North",Description:"The North zone of JVM Store",SortingOrder:0}}

Expected Output

0: Object
Name: Name of grouped zone which is "North"
Description: Description of grouped zone which is "The North zone of JVM Store"
Total: Count of North Zone with is 2

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BigRabbit hope now make it sense.